# PHP preg_match & preg_replace outputing wrong

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

```
<?php
$string = "[img image:left]1.jpg[/img]Example Text 1[img image:left]2.jpg[/img] Example Text 2";
preg_match("/\[img\s*[^>]+\s*\](.*?)\[\/\s*img\]/i", $string, $match);
$result = preg_replace("/\[img\s*[^>]+\s*\](.*?)\[\/\s*img\]/i", $match['1'], $string);
echo $result;
?>
```

When using this code it should output `1.jpg`, `Example Text 1`, `2.jpg`, `Example Text 2`.

But however it shows only `2.jpg`, `Example Text 2`.

I dont know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the time to format your question.

Comment: Thanks, i'll rephrase it the best i can, i'm new to coding didnt knew how to correctly write my question

Comment: @CarlosSantos: Your question was perfectly understandable, I was only speaking about the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There are two fundamental issues:*

- you don't need to use a `preg_match()` and a `preg_replace()`, you can just use `preg_replace()` and reference your capture groups in the substitution
- it looks like you copy pasted some code from HTML regex, and have `[^>]+` inside of your `[img]`, which says 1+ non-`>` characters..it should really be `[^\]]+`, 1+ non-`]` characters

*Final solution:*

```
$string = "[img image:left]1.jpg[/img]Example Text 1[img image:left]2.jpg[/img] Example Text 2";
$string = preg_replace("/\[img\s*[^\]]+\s*\](.*?)\[\/\s*img\]/i", ' \1 ', $string);
```

*Demo:* [RegEx](http://regex101.com/r/sW4jZ6) and [PHP](http://ideone.com/x12NRX)